# Is the error important when I use "Options -indexes" in my .htaccess file?

Tags: html, .htaccess

Okay, I'm a newbie when it comes to .htaccess files!  I am using this code in the .htaccess to "block" a folder full of images from listing its contents:

```
Options -indexes
```

This works well.  However, I get on the bottom of the Forbidden page: "Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request."

Do I need to do something further, or is this warning normal?  What does it mean?  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This means that you don't have a corresponding error document for handling 403s.  Add:

```
ErrorDocument 403 default
```

You can also point to a specific document

```
ErrorDocument 403 /forbidden.html
```